# "aren't currently targeting API level 28 or higher" yet my apps are all set to 28

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

I received an email from Google Play for my Apache Cordova Android apps:

> The apps included below have one or more APKs—in production or testing
>   tracks—that aren't currently targeting API level 28 or higher. Apps
>   are listed with the maximum version code and corresponding
>   targetSdkVersion.

However, double-checking an app with those version codes, I see that it is up to date.

**config.xml** has: `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28"`

platforms/android/**gradle.properties** has: `cdvTargetSdkVersion-28`

platforms/android/**build.gradle** has: `defaultTargetSdkVersin-28`

platforms/android/**project.properties** has: `target=android-28`

So I don't really know what to change to comply with the order. (I am not using phonegap.) I have installed platform android 8.1.0.

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is to ask Google to do a manual check.

Comment: What is your cordova-android version ?

Comment: @Swayangjit I'm at home right now, so I can't check. But it is the latest version.

Comment: Let me know if you are using cordova-android version 8 or not .

Comment: @Swayangjit I have android 8.1.0